# How to initialize an inputStream

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I'm trying to initialize an `InputStream`, but it is not allowing me. I have been able to initialize `OutputStream`.

```java
public void readData() {
  String fileName = "clinicData.txt";
  Scanner inputStream;
  System.out.println("The file " + fileName +"\ncontains the following line:\n");
  
  try {
      inputStream = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Error: opening the file " +fileName);
      System.exit(0);
  }
  while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = inputStream.nextLine();
      System.out.println (line);
  }
  inputStream.close();
}
```

The code above is the section I am working with if you need me to post the other section with the outputStream just tell me.

Comment: Well, you aren't initializing an `InputStream` but a `Scanner`. Is the question how to replace this code with code that uses an `InputStream`? Or is the usage of a `Scanner` intended and the code doesn't work? If it's the latter, what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: You should get your naming right to avoid confusion. Scanners and input streams are different things. You also should define "it is not allowing me", don't make us guess.

Comment: You're not trying to create an `InputStream`, you're creating a `Scanner`. You should be posting the error you get; your main problem seems to be variable scope though, because you read and close the scanner outside the scope it's initialized.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594252/how-to-initialize-an-inputstream-before-try-catch-block

Comment: The program does not work as it is an error straight up and I was told to use both Scanner and inputStream

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Initialize an InputStream Before Try/Catch Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594252/how-to-initialize-an-inputstream-before-try-catch-block)

Comment: @RemusCrisan I have looked at that it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
try (Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: opening the file " +fileName);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

- The `Scanner inputStream;` is initialized in the `try` block, however, it is not guaranteed the initialization succeeds and you would try to access such instance in the `while` loop later, which would be erroneous. Move the `while` loop **inside** the `try` block.
- `Scanner` is `AutoCloseable`, hence you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and omit `inputStream.close()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the file in `FileInputStream` and then read that using `Scanner` as shown below

```
try  
{  
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("clinicData.txt");       
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);

    while(sc.hasNextLine())  
        {  
          System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }  
    sc.close(); 
}  
catch(IOException e)  
{  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```